# Mysql table over 2000 columns

Tags: mysql, amazon-dynamodb

I have hourly table to store traffic/people, actions/people direction, visit area, etc. in the stores and the structure like this:

[image]

Key will be storeid,date,time. columns can up to 2000, 3000, etc. belong to the number of information we want to collect. As I know MySQL limited number of columns(InnoDB table), and I don't want to convert to MYISAM although it can up to 2000 columns.

**The question is: table structure is good or I need to use the others way to stored data.**

For ex: 
1. split this(tbl_data_hour) to 2 table.
2. Or I have to use others database server to do it, MS SQL(also limited column) or Amazon DynamoDB, my requirements is unlimited columns table.
3. ...

Comment: So you are adding columns every time a new `area_N` is added? You should really learn about Normalization and re-model your db. All those columns should be rows instead (like `storeid` and `time`).

Answer (score 1):

That sort of table structure is generally very very bad; a better solution is to have another `areas` table, having rows for each area; and a `store_areas_stats` table, with: `store_id`(referencing store table), `area_id`(referencing area table), and `area_count`(?) & `area_time` (representing the figures you were storing for each store area).

Edit: It looks like the table you've shown is more of a store_stats table itself; the `store_areas_stats` I suggested above should reference that table, not the stores table; which means you should probably put a primary key (auto increment) on the table you've shown.

Comment: the point is select speed, when you select a very long date range, 1 year for example. then the speed will be very slow.
anyway I have a thousand of stores so the data really huge

Comment: The speed difference will probably less significant than you expect; it is even possible normalizing the table structure like this will make queries faster.